# How to do an append to an existing field in a Django Model?

Tags: python, django

I have a model :

```
class Info(models.Model):
    m_id = models.IntegerField()
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

I want to be able to append data to message field. That is say for `m_id = 1` `message = 'Hello'` exists.

I want do a query that will add 'World' to `message` thus making it 'Hello World'

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify, then save.

```
someinfo.message += ' World'
someinfo.save()
```

Comment: Its that simple? I never thought of it. Thanks!